# How to reference a pointer from a function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So, I have the following struct

```
typedef struct DArray {
  int end;
  int max;
  size_t element_size;
  size_t expand_rate;
  void **contents;
} DArray;
```

**The reason I am using `void **contents` is because that's the way I have been told to reference the array from within the struct**

Here is how I am pushing values into contents

```
DArray *create_array() {
  DArray *result = DArray_create(sizeof(int), 5);
  int initial[] = {4,1,3,2,0};

  void *arr = (void *)(malloc(sizeof(void *) * 5));
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    *(int *)(arr + i * sizeof(int)) = initial[i];
  }
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("Pushing: %d\n", *(int *)(arr + i*sizeof(int)));
    DArray_push(result, (arr + i * sizeof(int)));
  }
  return result;
}

int DArray_push(DArray *array, void *el) {
    array->contents[array->end] = el;
    array->end++;

    if(DArray_end(array) > DArray_max(array)) {
      return DArray_expand(array);
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
}
```

I am then calling a quicksort function like so

```
int DArray_qsort(DArray *array, DArray_compare cmp) {
  quicksort(array->contents, DArray_count(array), sizeof(void *), cmp);
  return 0;
}
```

Then I try to iterate over `array->contents` using the following function

```
void quicksort(void *contents, int count, size_t elem, DArray_compare cmp) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("Value: %d\n", *((char *)contents + (i * sizeof(int))));
  }
  return;
}
```

But, I end up with garbage values

However, the following seems to work

```
int DArray_qsort(DArray *array, DArray_compare cmp) {
  quicksort(array, DArray_count(array), sizeof(void *), cmp);
  return 0;
}
void quicksort(DArray *array, int count, size_t elem, DArray_compare cmp) {
  int i = 0;
  for(i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("Value: %d\n", *(int *)(array->contents[i]));
  }
  return;
}
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: @coderredoc What do you mean by full code? Is there something specific you want to see?

Comment: So, do you need me to post the code where I am actually building the struct by assigning values? I'm just confused which part of the code you want me to post, sorry.

Comment: Again: ideally, you'll post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), i.e. **all** the code that readers need to replicate the problem, and no more code than that.

Comment: Okay, updated the question again. This should be enough to produce an MVCE.

Comment: Thanks, but an MCVE is not something that readers should have to "produce" from materials you give them; it's a single piece of code they can immediately copy/paste and compile. In other words, there would be a `main()` function that would perform whatever steps you currently are and that replicate the issue. That's not this: for example, `DArray_create()` is totally missing, so what's the point of readers trying to guess what it's doing and how that may affect the observed output? Anyway, your 'good' and 'bad' examples are very different: the 'bad' one prints `char`s as if `int`s, which is UB

Comment: The *intention* of the code is not very clear. Do you want to construct some kind of "universal container" ? (then:  *why* the `void**` ??)

Comment: We shouldn’t have to produce an MCVE; you should produce an MCVE. We can’t tell what weird thing you’ve done that we haven’t guessed that is breaking things.  You don’t seem to set `element_size` in the structure.  Is that part of the problem?

Comment: Also, what is the precise purpose of this overly elaborate dance? `*((char *)contents + (i * sizeof(int)))` Why not just index? You already did elsewhere. Do you have some grander plan that mandates such opaque code instead of the simpler solutions that everyone will keep recommending if you don't explain what you're trying to do and why?

Comment: Okay, I have taken the comments into consideration, and tried once again to post an MVCE. This code should compile directly. Apologies for all the opaqueness earlier. Wasn't aware how much of a pain it was going to be to figure out how the code works.

Comment: Sry, had to rollback your last edit. As changing the question massively after answers /comments had been given might render those ununderstandable. Please add "changes" as additions.

Comment: `(arr + i * sizeof(int))` is non standard conforming.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
DArray_push(result, (arr + i * sizeof(int)));
```

you pass addresses of a *local* variable, namely `initial`.

The stuff they point to is dead and gone when `create_array()` had been left.

No matter what you try those values pointed to may not be accessed any more then.

---

Assuming the former would not be an issue, you do not treat the `int*`s stored as such when printing them here:

```
   printf("Value: %d\n", *((char *)contents + (i * sizeof(int))))
```

But instead of casting the `void`-pointers back to `int*`, the code casts them  back the to `char*` and dereferences them.

---

Also you define

```
void *arr = ...
```

and afterwards apply pointer arithmetic to the `void`-pointer `arr`:

```
   *(int *)(arr + i * sizeof(int)) = ...
```

Doing so is *not* defined by the C Standard, but a vendor specific extension to the language.